# How can I use Excel files for Time Series Analysis in R?

Tags: r, excel, file-upload, time-series

I am somewhat new to R, but I have been studying Time Series Analysis. In the link below I was reading about all the codes for Time Series in R and it was relatively straight forward- except for the first step. It tells me to upload the data, I imported my excel file into R but when I enter the code - data("Table2)" it does not work.

I am referring to Step 1 in the link. [Link to the codes for Time series](https://rpubs.com/JSHAH/481706)

Comment: If you've imported data into R via RStudio menu interfaces or `read.csv` or `openxlsx::...`, then don't use `data(.)`. That function is used for retrieving data that is distributed with a package, not something you work with locally. For example, `data(package="ggplot2")` shows you a list of 11 datasets that the `ggplot2` package provides, in this case as examples useful in the help docs. Other packages may use exported datasets for production/operational purposes, not just demonstrative.

Comment: If you imported the data from the excel file (csv? xlsx?) into R, is it stored in `Table2` (no quotes)?

Comment: In that post they are using a data set from base package `datasets`, they are not using an Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? You need to install packege for reading excel.

```
install.packeges("readxl")
library(readxl)
data<- read_excel("mydata.xlsx")
View(data)
```

You can also try:

```
Require("readxl")
```

you can also read about importing data and packages here:
[Packages for reading data in R](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2921176/great-r-packages-for-data-import-wrangling-visualization.html)

Comment: Hi, It worked thank you so much! The files are now uploaded